# How to stop interval on function?

Tags: javascript, html

I got function, which is interval. And I need to stop it when it finishes. here is the code:

```
 function cut() {
    setInterval(function() {
       timer()
    }, 1000);
 }


 function timer() {

    seconds = seconds - 1;
    document.getElementById("timer1").innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if (seconds < 10) {
       document.getElementById("timer1").innerHTML = minutes + ":" + "0" + seconds
    }
    if (seconds <= 0) {
       clearInterval("cut()");


       //another code to be executed
    }
 }
```

can I use this clearInterval for function at all? or there is another solution for doing that?

Thanks :)

Comment: Put it in a variable; `var myInterval = setInterval(...)` and then use `clearInterval(myInterval);` to stop it.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 3):

You have to keep a reference to the handle returned from `setInterval()` and then pass it to `clearInterval()` like so:

```
var cutHandle;

function cut() {
    cutHandle = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

function timer() {
    seconds = seconds - 1;
    var timer = document.getElementById("timer1");
    timer.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if (seconds < 10) {
        timer.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + "0" + seconds
    }
    if (seconds <= 0) {
        clearInterval(cutHandle);
        //another code to be executed
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want more help, post a complete [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we have a greater context.

Answer (score 2):

Save your interval in a variable:

```
var myInterval= setInterval(function(){//your code here},1000);

//whenever you want to end the interval, call:
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

Thus, your cut() function should changed to this:

```
var myInterval;
function cut() {
    myInterval = setInterval(function() {timer()}, 1000);
}
function clear(){
    clearInterval(myInterval);
}

// the rest of your code:
function timer() {
    seconds = seconds - 1;
    document.getElementById("timer1").innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if (seconds < 10) {
        document.getElementById("timer1").innerHTML = minutes + ":" + "0" + seconds
    }
    if (seconds <= 0) {
       clear();

       //another code to be executed
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you please check the question again?

Comment: Updated to put it in situation. Is this better?

Comment: Uhm. the thing is I need to call cut onclick

Comment: by cut() you mean that on click, you need to start the interval?

Comment: I have div that contains button, and when its clicked it must start cut() which starts interval

Comment: answer has been updated; cut() is your original function while clear() cancels the interval.